# Cannot get this mod rewrite rule to work

Tags: php, apache

Here is what i have

```
RewriteRule ^/articles/category/([0-9]+)/$ ./index.php?module=articles&view=cat&catid=$1
```

I must be missing something?

Just trying to get the "catid" and nothing else.

Comment: Removing the dot does nothing.

Comment: Is this in the server config, or in .htaccess?  If it's the latter, the beginning slash will be stripped off, so the url will look like `articles/category/12345`.

Comment: Why do you think you're missing something? What do you mean by "does not work"? What happens? What does the log output say? What have you tried? What research have you performed?

Comment: Does not work = well it doesn't work, what usually happens when a write rule is fubared..404

Answer (score 4):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/category/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?module=articles&view=cat&catid=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Please remember that **RewriteRule starts matching a URI after striping out leading slash `/`**

Some flags added are:

- L : Last Rule
- QSA : Query String Append
- NC : Ignore Case Comparison

Comment: Wow awesome that works! Mind explaining this a little more what your additions changed? Just so i can properly learn rather than copy paste.

Comment: Added some explanation with my answer.

Comment: Thanks but i don't get the bit in bold though thats the only bit i now dont understand?

Comment: Your RewriteRule had this regex `^/articles/category/([0-9]+)/$` which has a leading slash `/` and that cannot work because of the explanation given in bold text in my answer.

Comment: You're welcome, pls don't forget to accept this answer if you're satisfied.